# Can I create AxesSubplot objects, then add them to a Figure instance?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Looking at the `matplotlib` documentation, it seems the standard way to add an `AxesSubplot` to a `Figure` is to use `Figure.add_subplot`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.hist( some params .... )
```

I would like to be able to create `AxesSubPlot`-like objects independently of the figure, so I can use them in different figures. Something like

```
fig = pyplot.figure()
histoA = some_axes_subplot_maker.hist( some params ..... )
histoA = some_axes_subplot_maker.hist( some other params ..... )
# make one figure with both plots
fig.add_subaxes(histo1, 211)
fig.add_subaxes(histo1, 212)
fig2 = pyplot.figure()
# make a figure with the first plot only
fig2.add_subaxes(histo1, 111)
```

Is this possible in `matplotlib` and if so, how can I do this?

**Update:** I have not managed to decouple creation of Axes and Figures, but following examples in the answers below, can easily re-use previously created axes in new or olf Figure instances. This can be illustrated with a simple function:

```
def plot_axes(ax, fig=None, geometry=(1,1,1)):
    if fig is None:
        fig = plt.figure()
    if ax.get_geometry() != geometry :
        ax.change_geometry(*geometry)
    ax = fig.axes.append(ax)
    return fig
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Typically, you just pass the axes instance to a function.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def main():
    x = np.linspace(0, 6 * np.pi, 100)

    fig1, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
    plot(x, np.sin(x), ax1)
    plot(x, np.random.random(100), ax2)

    fig2 = plt.figure()
    plot(x, np.cos(x))

    plt.show()

def plot(x, y, ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    line, = ax.plot(x, y, 'go')
    ax.set_ylabel('Yabba dabba do!')
    return line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To respond to your question, you could always do something like this:

```
def subplot(data, fig=None, index=111):
    if fig is None:
        fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(index)
    ax.plot(data)
```

Also, you can simply add an axes instance to another figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(10))

fig2 = plt.figure()
fig2.axes.append(ax)

plt.show()
```

Resizing it to match other subplot "shapes" is also possible, but it's going to quickly become more trouble than it's worth.  The approach of just passing around a figure or axes instance (or list of instances) is much simpler for complex cases, in my experience...

Comment: +1 This is useful, but it seems to me that the axes are still coupled to the figures, and/or to some state in pyplot. I cannot really decouple the axis creation from the figure making and plotting following your example.

Comment: Axes are fundamentally linked to a specific figure in matplotlib. There's no way around this. However, you can still completely "decouple the axis creation from the figure making and plotting" by just passing axes and figure objects around. I'm not quite sure I follow what you're wanting to do...

Comment: Well, actually, I guess they're not as fundementally linked as I thought.  You can just add the same axes to a different figure. (Just do `fig2.axes.append(ax1)`) Resizing it to match different subplot shapes is also possible. This is probably going to wind up being more trouble than it's worth, though...

Comment: I think I can achieve what I want appending to Figure.axes as in your example, plus re-sizing the AxesSubPlot with change_geometry.

Comment: adding axes instance to another figure (last example) doesn't work for me in Enthought 7.3-2 (matplotlib 1.1.0).

Comment: @aaren - It's not working because the way the axes stack for a figure works has been changed in newer versions of matplotlib. Axes deliberately aren't supposed to be shared between different figures now. As a workaround, you could do this `fig2._axstack.add(fig2._make_key(a), a)`, but it's hackish and likely to change in the future.  It seems to work properly, but it may break some things.

Comment: yeah, I wouldn't actually do it that way anyway. passing the axes to a function that plots on it makes more sense as it decouples figure layout and axes creation (layout) from the actual plotting (content)

Comment: 10 years later and I still wonder why I insist on using `matplotlib`

Comment: Spending the whole morning to get here and it does not work (fig2 is blank).

Answer (score 39):

The following shows how to "move" an axes from one figure to another. This is the intended functionality of [@JoeKington's last example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6309636/4124317), which in newer matplotlib versions is not working anymore, because axes cannot live in several figures at once.

You would first need to remove the axes from the first figure, then append it to the next figure and give it some position to live in.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(10))
ax.remove()

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax.figure=fig2
fig2.axes.append(ax)
fig2.add_axes(ax)

dummy = fig2.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_position(dummy.get_position())
dummy.remove()
plt.close(fig1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: small addition: when `plt.show()` is replaced by `fig2.savefig('out.png', dpi=300)` the positioning is messed up due to the `dpi` keyword. This can be avoided by setting the final `dpi` when `ax` is initialized: `fig1, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=300)`

Comment: In my Python shell, it doesn't look like this line does anything:

    fig2.axes.append(ax)

Comment: `ax.remove()` results in `NotImplementedError: cannot remove artist` (Python 3.7.0, matplotlib 2.2.2)

Comment: @gerrit Did you change anything compared to the snippet above? It works fine for me.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes; I obtained my figure from a `pickle`.  I apologise for omitting this important detail.  I ended up setting 9 AxesSubplot to `set_visible(False)` and changing the position of the one I wanted to show only.

Comment: @gerrit Maybe you need [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48915069/4124317)?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Maybe.  I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6310298/974555), but the call to `add_line` resulted in `RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure`.  Meanwhile I've found a different workaround, though.

Comment: @Matthias123 I got the same problem and used your solution to fix the `.png` output, but it doesn't work if I change the extension to `.eps`. Any ideas how to make the eps look the same as the png and plt.show() output? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @irene Note that this solution only moves the axes to a new figure, it does not set any of the transforms. So such issues are expected. Since it is discouraged to move artists between figures, better don't use this if you need reliable output.

Comment: based on this and on the update on the question I tried the following code: https://gist.github.com/homerobse/d8b4cbaff3125f0404c77dc90c21abe0
The axes went to the new figure, but they did not resize appropriately to the size of the new figure. Also, when trying to `fig.savefig('newfig-witholdaxes.svg', format='svg')` it was cut in different places than the one displayed with `plt.show()`

Comment: How would this work if the second figure was given by `fig2, ax=plt.subplots(ncols=2); ax=ax.flatten()`?

Comment: Remark, `ax.remove()` can also be `fig.delaxes(ax)`.

Answer (score 4):

For line plots, you can deal with the `Line2D` objects themselves:

```
fig1 = pylab.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
lines = ax1.plot(scipy.randn(10))

fig2 = pylab.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
ax2.add_line(lines[0])
```

Comment: +1 Good example. It seems I cannot decouple the axes creation from figure creation, but I can grab the axes instance and pass it to new figures.

Comment: Please note that this approach does not work anymore. See Joe Kington's comment from Dec 7 2012, on his answer above.

Comment: `ax2.add_line(lines[0])` results in `RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure` (Python 3.7.0, matplotlib 2.2.2).

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** based partly on [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325565/joe-kington) nice answer.

Opt.1: `fig.add_subplot()`

```
def fcn_return_plot():
    return plt.plot(np.random.random((10,)))
n = 4
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(n*3,2))
#fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, n,  sharey=True, figsize=(n*3,2)) # also works
for index in list(range(n)):
    fig.add_subplot(1, n, index + 1)
    fcn_return_plot()
    plt.title(f"plot: {index}", fontsize=20)
```

Opt.2: pass `ax[index]` to a function that returns `ax[index].plot()`

```
def fcn_return_plot_input_ax(ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    return ax.plot(np.random.random((10,)))
n = 4
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, n,  sharey=True, figsize=(n*3,2))
for index in list(range(n)):
    fcn_return_plot_input_ax(ax[index])
    ax[index].set_title(f"plot: {index}", fontsize=20)
```

Outputs respect.
[image]
[image]

Note: Opt.1 `plt.title()` changed in opt.2 to `ax[index].set_title()`. Find more [Matplotlib Gotchas in Van der Plas book](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.01-simple-line-plots.html#Aside:-Matplotlib-Gotchas).

Answer (score 0):

To go deeper in the rabbit hole. Extending my previous answer, one could return a whole `ax`, and not `ax.plot()` only. E.g.

If dataframe had 100 tests of 20 types (here id):

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,3)), columns = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3'])
dfB = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(list(range(20)),5), columns = ['id'])
dfC = dfA.join(dfB)
```

And the plot function (this is the key of this whole answer):

```
def plot_feature_each_id(df, feature, id_range=[], ax=None, legend_bool=False):
    feature = df[feature]
    if not len(id_range): id_range=set(df['id'])
    legend_arr = []
    for k in id_range:
        pass
        mask = (df['id'] == k)
        ax.plot(feature[mask])
        legend_arr.append(f"id: {k}")
    if legend_bool: ax.legend(legend_arr)
    return ax
```

We can achieve:

```
feature_arr = dfC.drop('id',1).columns
id_range= np.random.randint(len(set(dfC.id)), size=(10,))
n = len(feature_arr)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, n,  figsize=(n*6,4));
for i,k in enumerate(feature_arr):
    plot_feature_each_id(dfC, k, np.sort(id_range), ax[i], legend_bool=(i+1==n))
    ax[i].set_title(k, fontsize=20)
    ax[i].set_xlabel("test nr. (id)", fontsize=20)
```

[image]