# matplotlib - duplicate plot from one figure to another?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm somewhat new to matplotlib. What I'm trying to do is write code that saves several figures to eps files, and then generates a composite figure. Basically what I'd like to do is have something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

def my_plot_1():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ...
    return fig

def my_plot_2():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ...
    return fig

def my_combo_plot(fig1,fig2):
    fig = plt.figure()
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2)
    ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0,0])
    ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[0,1])
    ax1 COPY fig1
    ax2 COPY fig2
    ...
```

where then later I could do something like

```
my_combo_plot( my_plot_1() , my_plot_2() )
```

and have all the data and settings get copied from the plots returned by the first two functions, but I can't figure out how this would be done with matplotlib.

Comment: It's possible to move them around (to duplicate them you can pickle then unpickle). https://stackoverflow.com/a/46906599/5267751 shows how to move it from one figure to another, but I've yet to figure out how to put it in a particular subplot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since pyplot kind of works like a state machine, I'm not sure if what you are asking for is possible.  I would instead factor out the drawing code, something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def my_plot_1(ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    ax.plot([1, 2, 3], 'b-')

def my_plot_2(ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    ax.plot([3, 2, 1], 'ro')

def my_combo_plot():
    ax1 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
    ax2 = plt.subplot(1,2,2)
    my_plot_1(ax1)
    my_plot_2(ax2)
```

Comment: This is the best solution IMHO. I just wanted to add that, now that figures are picklable, technically it is also possible to copy a figure instance - you can even do this from one backend to another.

Comment: This might be a quick work around but is not an answer. If you have "plotting instructions" that take a lot of time, this solution is not feasible. Say that I have a 3D plot and want to show, in 3 subplots, XZ,YZ and XY views. In principle you could use the same plot and change the view. With this solution, you simply plot 3 times instead of once and change the view. (Unfortunately, I also don't know how to achieve this). Someone?

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46906599/5267751 it's possible to move the axes from one figure to other (using `pickle` it's also possible to keep the old figure).

Add `set_subplotspec` to position the resulting axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

def my_plot_1():
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot([1, 2, 3], 'b-')
    return fig

def my_plot_2():
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot([3, 2, 1], 'ro')
    return fig

fig1 = my_plot_1()
fig2 = my_plot_2()

def my_combo_plot(fig1,fig2):
    fig = plt.figure()
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2)

    ax1 = fig1.axes[0]
    ax1.remove()
    ax1.figure = fig
    fig.add_axes(ax1)
    ax1.set_subplotspec(gs[0, 0])

    ax2 = fig2.axes[0]
    ax2.remove()
    ax2.figure = fig
    fig.add_axes(ax2)
    ax2.set_subplotspec(gs[0, 1])

    plt.close(fig1)
    plt.close(fig2)

my_combo_plot( my_plot_1() , my_plot_2() )

plt.show()
```

The code assumes that each figure contains exactly one axes, however.