# matplotlib: combine different figures and put them in a single subplot sharing a common legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

We have a code that [creates figures from input.txt files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g646f1wghktrl1b/matplotlib-combine-different-figures-and-put-them-in-a-single-subplot-sharing-a.zip). We need to combine 2 of these figures in a single subplot. The data from figure1 will be plotted in the left subplot and from figure2 in the right subplot, sharing the same legend and witht he same scale in axes x and y:

[image]

Here there is some example data:

```
x  = [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 100, 1000 ]
y1 = [ 1, 0.822, 0.763, 0.715, 0.680, 0.648, 0.645 ]
y2 = [ 1, 0.859, 0.812, 0.774, 0.746, 0.721, 0.718 ]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# mode 01 from one case
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot( x, y1, label='mode 01' )
# mode 01 from other case
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
ax2.plot( x, y2, label='mode 01' )
```

---

EDIT: the method suggested by @nordev works. Now it would be really convenient to pass the ax1 and ax2 objects to the new figure, since they have much more information. [It seems that there is no straightforward way to achieve that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309472/matplotlib-can-i-create-axessubplot-objects-then-add-them-to-a-figure-instance#comment18919455_6309636).

The [real case has been made available here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g646f1wghktrl1b/matplotlib-combine-different-figures-and-put-them-in-a-single-subplot-sharing-a.zip). To make it work, please run `plot_both.py`.

---

EDIT2: it was easier to change the routine that reads the input.txt files. [Now it supports multiple plots](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ekywe8m3f8vh6j4/matplotlib-combine-different-figures-and-put-them-in-a-single-subplot-sharing-a-new.zip). But the question is still valid because it would be great to treat the `AxesSubplot` as an easily interchangeable object among different figures, subplots and so forth...

Comment: Just to be clear: you are not able to simply plot these data as two subplots in one figure, using the `sharey` option? You have to create two separate figures, and thereafter extract the plots and combine them in a new figure?

Comment: I tried the sharey option, but it seems to only share [the axis limits and views](http://matplotlib.org/users/recipes.html), not the data itself... and the current code create these individual figures, I would like to try combining them before changing this code...

Comment: I still don't fully understand what it is you want to achieve. From the example plot you included (image #1), the y-axis is shared, and the data in each plot is plotted _only in one subplot_, i.e. the plots are independent. From your comment above, it seems that you want _both_ lines to be plotted in _both_ subplots? If you want, say, line number 1 plotted only in subplot number 1, and line 2 plotted only in subplot number 2, where the y-axis has the same limits (shared y-axis), this is pretty easy. Also, can't you simply call the `plot` method with the same arguments as in `ax1.plot(...`?

Comment: I edited the question, please check if it is clear now...

Comment: Have you found any solution to the original problem, other than basically doing what I've suggested below (make the plots subplots of the same figure, rather than subplots of two separate figures)?

Comment: @nordev The suggestion to make the subplots of the same figure is probably the best practice in `Matplotlib 1.2.1`. I haven't seen your EDIT. Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
x  = [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 100, 1000 ]
y1 = [ 1, 0.822, 0.763, 0.715, 0.680, 0.648, 0.645 ]
y2 = [ 1, 0.859, 0.812, 0.774, 0.746, 0.721, 0.718 ]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import BlendedGenericTransform
# mode 01 from one case
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
line1, = ax1.plot( x, y1, label='mode 01' )
# mode 01 from other case
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
line2, = ax2.plot( x, y2, label='mode 01' )

# Create new figure and two subplots, sharing both axes
fig3, (ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(1,2,sharey=True, sharex=True,figsize=(10,5))

# Plot data from fig1 and fig2
line3, = ax3.plot(line1.get_data()[0], line1.get_data()[1])
line4, = ax4.plot(line2.get_data()[0], line2.get_data()[1])
# If possible (easy access to plotting data) use
# ax3.plot(x, y1)
# ax4.lpot(x, y2)

ax3.set_ylabel('y-axis')
ax3.grid(True)
ax4.grid(True)

# Add legend
fig3.legend((line3, line4),
            ('label 3', 'label 4'),
            loc = 'upper center',
            bbox_to_anchor = [0.5, -0.05],
            bbox_transform = BlendedGenericTransform(fig3.transFigure, ax3.transAxes))
# Make space for the legend beneath the subplots
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.2)
# Show only fig3
fig3.show()
```

This gives output as seen below
[image]

## Edit

Looking at the code in your uploaded zip-file, I'd say most of the requested functionality is achieved?

I see you have changed the function creating the plots, making the solution to your problem radically different, as you are no longer trying to "merge" two subplots from different figures. Your solution is basically the same as the one I presented above, in the sense that both are creating both `Axes` instances as subplots on the same figure (giving the desired layout), and *then* plotting, rather than *plotting, then extract/move the axes*, as your question was concerning originally.

As I suspected, the easiest and most trivial solution is to make the individual `Axes` subplots of the same figure instead of having them tied to separate figures, as moving one `Axes` instance from one `Figure` to another is not easily accomplished (if at all possible), as specified in a comment. The "original" problem still seems to be very hard to accomplish, as simply adding an `Axes` instance to the `Figure`'s `_axstack` makes it hard to customize to the desired layout.

One modification to the `ax.legend(...` of your current code, to make the legend centered horizontally, with the top just below the axes:

```
# Add this line
from matplotlib.transforms import BlendedGenericTransform

# Edit the function call to use the BlendedGenericTransform
ax.legend(loc='upper center',
          ncol=7,
          labelspacing=-0.7,
          columnspacing=0.75,
          fontsize=8,
          handlelength=2.6,
          markerscale=0.75,
          bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
          bbox_transform=BlendedGenericTransform(fig.transFigure, ax.transAxes))
```

Here, the `bbox_to_anchor` argument should be customized to fit within the boundaries of our figure.

The [`BlendedGenericTransform`](http://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html?highlight=blendedgenerictransform#matplotlib.transforms.BlendedGenericTransform) allows the transforms of the x-axis and y-axis to be different, which can be very useful in many situations.

Comment: thank you very much! It works, now I am trying to pass to the new figure the `AxesSubplot` object, to take all the information from fig1 and fig2 more efficiently...

Comment: @SaulloCastro According to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309472/matplotlib-can-i-create-axessubplot-objects-then-add-them-to-a-figure-instance#comment18919455_6309636) by Joe Kington (December '12), `Axes` instances deliberately aren't supposed to be shared between figures, making your request pretty hard to accomplish.

Comment: I updated the question with a link to the real case just in case you want do play with it...

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue, trying to merge in a single matplotlib figure  axes built with different python packages for which I can't easily access the data.

I could make a dirty work around, by saving the images as a png file, then reimporting them as images and create axes based on it.

Here's a function doing it (It's ugly, and you'll need to adapt it, but it does the job).

```
import cairosvg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

def merge_2axes(fig1,fig2,file_name1="f1.png",file_name2="f2.png"):

  fig1.savefig(file_name1)
  fig2.savefig(file_name2)


  fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(30, 30))
  if file_name1[-3:] == "svg":
    img_png = cairosvg.svg2png(url=file_name1)
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_png))
    ax1.imshow(img)
  else:
    ax1.imshow(plt.imread(file_name1))
  if file_name2[-3:] == "svg":
    img_png = cairosvg.svg2png(url=file_name2)
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_png))
    ax2.imshow(img)
  else:  
    ax2.imshow(plt.imread(file_name2))


  for ax in (ax1, ax2):
      for side in ('top', 'left', 'bottom', 'right'):
          ax.spines[side].set_visible(False)
      ax.tick_params(left=False, right=False, labelleft=False,
                     labelbottom=False, bottom=False)


  return fig
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Could you do the same while saving as PDF or another vector graphic format?

Comment: I just cleaned the function a bit, and added the option to use svg format for the temporary files. Thanks for the suggestion, it's better this way I think :). Hope this help!

Answer (score 4):

I've extended [@hulyce's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74337708/10133797) to account for different figure sizes, but only for vertically stacking different heights with shared width. Unfortunately there's resampling-related blur that I'm unsure how to deal with. Though there's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56777678/10133797) which is clearly better for some purposes.

```py
def merge_2axes(fig1,fig2,file_name1="f1.png",file_name2="f2.png"):
  fig1.savefig(file_name1)
  fig2.savefig(file_name2)
  
  # inherit figures' dimensions, partially
  h1, h2 = [int(np.ceil(fig.get_figheight())) for fig in (fig1, fig2)]
  wmax = int(np.ceil(max([fig.get_figwidth() for fig in (fig1, fig2)])))

  fig, axes = plt.subplots(h1 + h2, figsize=(wmax, h1 + h2))
  
  # make two axes of desired height proportion
  gs = axes[0].get_gridspec()
  for ax in axes.flat:
      ax.remove()
  ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:h1])
  ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[h1:])

  ax1.imshow(plt.imread(file_name1))
  ax2.imshow(plt.imread(file_name2))

  for ax in (ax1, ax2):
      for side in ('top', 'left', 'bottom', 'right'):
          ax.spines[side].set_visible(False)
      ax.tick_params(left=False, right=False, labelleft=False,
                     labelbottom=False, bottom=False)

  return fig
```