# Combine two matplotlib Figures, side by side, high quality

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I produced two matplotlib Figures, at size of 1000x1000.
Each of the figures is 4x4 subplots based figure.
I want one figure at size of 1000x2000 (width is 2000).

```py
fig1
<Figure size 1000x1000 with 4 Axes>

fig2
<Figure size 1000x1000 with 4 Axes>
```

Now I want to combine them together.

I've searched many references:
[How to make two plots side-by-side using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42818361/how-to-make-two-plots-side-by-side-using-python)

[Plotting two figures side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60223045/plotting-two-figures-side-by-side)

[Adding figures to subplots in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279217/adding-figures-to-subplots-in-matplotlib)

They are not relevant because mostly they suggest to change the way the initial plots were created. I don't want to change it - I want to use the Figure as is.

I just need to place Fig1 to the left of Fig2. Not changing the way Fig1 or Fig2 were created.

I also tried using PIL method: https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-concat-images/
However it was lower quality

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can render your figures to arrays using the `agg` backend.
Then concat the arrays side by side and switch back to your normal backend to show the result:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

backend = mpl.get_backend()
mpl.use('agg')

dpi = 100
fig1,_ = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(1000/dpi, 1000/dpi), dpi=dpi)
fig1.suptitle('Figure 1')
fig2,_ = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(1000/dpi, 1000/dpi), dpi=dpi)
fig2.suptitle('Figure 2')

c1 = fig1.canvas
c2 = fig2.canvas

c1.draw()
c2.draw()

a1 = np.array(c1.buffer_rgba())
a2 = np.array(c2.buffer_rgba())
a = np.hstack((a1,a2))

mpl.use(backend)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2000/dpi, 1000/dpi), dpi=dpi)
fig.subplots_adjust(0, 0, 1, 1)
ax.set_axis_off()
ax.matshow(a)
```

[image]

Comment: It reduces the quality of the images. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It doesn't reduce the quality of the images itself (as you take both rendered images and just concat their data), but showing the combined image in a matshow or imshow may reduce the quality of the *displayed* result if you need to shrink the combined image to make if fit to your screen (depending on figsize and interpolation settings). I attached the result to the answer and there's no quality reduction (of course you need to view the image at 100 % zoom level)

Comment: Can plots added this way be resized relative to one another? What if I want them to share the available width at a 2:1 ratio, for example?

Comment: @Mandias you could make `fig1` `1333/dpi` wide and `fig2` `667/dpi`, so that the resulting figure keeps the same size but the ratio would be 2:1

Answer (score 2):

Not directly merging two seperate figures, but I succeeded achieving the final goal by using this reference:
https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html

That's the code I needed:

```
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(20, 11))
titles_size = 25
labels_size = 18
subfigs = fig.subfigures(1, 2, wspace=0.02)
subfigs[0].suptitle('Title 1', fontsize=titles_size)
subfigs[1].suptitle('Title 2', fontsize=titles_size)

axsLeft = subfigs[0].subplots(2, 2)
axsRight = subfigs[1].subplots(2, 2)

for ax_idx, ax in enumerate(axsLeft.reshape(-1)):
    ax.grid(False)
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)
for ax_idx, ax in enumerate(axsRight.reshape(-1)):
    ax.grid(False)
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax.axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image: result]