# How to concatenate three or more images vertically?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, image-manipulation, scikit-image

I try to concatenate three images vertically and I need some assistance with the code/function. So far I imported one image and cropped 3 smaller images with the same size. Now I want to concatenate them in one image that will be long, but narrow. However, I can't find an appropriate function or even if I find one I get an error message when I apply it to my code.

I already tried to make a collection from my three pictures and then use the function skimage.io.concatenate_images(sf_collection), but this results in a 4-dimensional picture that cannot be visualized.

```
sf_collection = (img1,img2,img3)
concat_page = skimage.io.concatenate_images(sf_collection)
```

My expected output is the three images to be concatenated vertically in one image (very long and narrow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ive never used `skimage.io.concatenate`, but I think you are looking for [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).  It defaults to `axis=0`, but you can specify `axis=1` for a horizontal stack.  This also assumes you have already loaded the images into their array from.

```
from scipy.misc import face
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

face1 = face()
face2 = face()
face3 = face()

merge = np.concatenate((face1,face2,face3))

plt.gray()
plt.imshow(merge)
```

which returns:
[image]

If you look at the [`skimage.io.concatenate_images` docs](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/io/collection.py#L19), it's using `np.concatenate` too. It seems like that function provides a data structure to hold collections of images, but not merge into a single image.

Comment: I think you beat me by 40 seconds :-)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
import numpy as np

h, w = 100, 400

yellow = np.zeros((h,w,3),dtype=np.uint8) + np.array([255,255,0],dtype=np.uint8)
red    = np.zeros((h,w,3),dtype=np.uint8) + np.array([255,0,0],dtype=np.uint8)
blue   = np.zeros((h,w,3),dtype=np.uint8) + np.array([0,0,255],dtype=np.uint8)

# Stack vertically
result = np.vstack((yellow,red,blue))
```

[image]

Use the following to stack side-by-side (horizontally):

```
result = np.hstack((yellow,red,blue))
```