# Make subplot of existing matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Suppose I have created two figures, each with two subplots. See the code below. I would like the two figures to be subplots of another figure. What would be a simple a way to achieve this? (I am interested in **nested** subplots.)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y = [1,3,4,2,5,7,6]
z = [5,4,4,2,3,2,1]

fig1, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2) 
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,z)

fig2, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2) 
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,z)

plt.show()
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611722) points in the right direction but I am confused about how to add the axis. My "solution" below does not work.

```
fig = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[1,1])

figure1, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(fig[0])
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,z)

figure2, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(fig[1])
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,z)
```

(Apologies if this is a stupid question, I just started learning Python.)

Answer (score -1):

You could try a solution similar to this.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
y = [1,3,4,2,5,7,6]
z = [5,4,4,2,3,2,1]
z1 = [5,4,4,2,3,2,1]


fig, ((ax1, ax2, ax3)) = plt.subplots(1, 3)

ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,z)
ax3.plot(x, z1)
plt.show()
```