# How to combine multiple matplotlib figures into one figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

to start with, I've 2 function which I have no control of and each of the function return a figure of type matplotlib.figure.Figure.

Each figure from the function can have multiple axes inside. I want to combine both of the figure from previous function I mentioned into single figure (or image I guess).
Each of the figure returned from previous function will be a new subplot for the new figure.

I tried to browse similar question, but I can't find something similar to my case (I'm sorry if I'm wrong. Please correct me)

Thank you!

Comment: This is to be something that comes up quite a lot, but there seems to be no reliable way of doing it https://stackoverflow.com/a/22585699/1862861. There are several slightly hacky ways that may or may not work for you, e.g., save the original figures and add them as images into a new figure https://stackoverflow.com/a/75824055/1862861, extract data from the figures and replot https://stackoverflow.com/a/16750010/1862861, remove an axes from one figure and add it to another https://stackoverflow.com/a/46906599/1862861.

Answer (score 0):

More details are needed to know if you want to combine everything in one axis or in one figure with many subplots.

In any case, you can store the figures after generating them with the function `fig_1 = plt.gcf()`.

From there, you can get the axes by `ax_1 = fig_1.axes`

And then you can get the data from each axis by using

```
x = ax_1[0].lines[0].get_xdata()
y = ax_1[0].lines[0].get_ydata()
```

Feel free to use the data however you want.

To save the final plot, use `plt.savefig("....", dpi = 300)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited my question, hope it will be clearer now.
As for the answer, It seems getting the data and re-plotting it wouldn't work. 
The shape of the actual plot are quite complex and for now, I would like to avoid the method

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I just edited the reply again, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Seems that maybe the plot is not for example 3 plots in a row or 3 plots in a column, but rather a pattern? maybe 2x2? Again, we cannot be more helpful unless you give us a screenshot or something. try maybe ax_1[0,0] instead of ax_1[0]. Or better yet, you can vectorize the axis object by using ax_1 = ax_1.flatten().