# GridSpec of multiple subplots "the figure containing the passed axes is being cleared"

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, subplot

I have 4 different `df.hist(columns=, by=)` that I would like to insert inside of a GridSpec(2, 2).

Each one of them looks like this :

[image]

Here is the code :

```
stuff = [df1, df2, df4, df3]
col = ['blue', 'orange', 'grey', 'green']
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)

for i in range(0, len(stuff)):
    ax = plt.subplot(gs[i])
    stuff[i].hist(column='quanti_var', by=stuff[i].quali_var, alpha=.5, color=col[i], ax=ax)
```

I'm having the following UserWarning :

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py:3234: UserWarning: To output multiple subplots, the figure containing the passed axes is being cleared
  "is being cleared", UserWarning)
```

and not the output I am looking for :

[image]

I tried several things including the use of `SubplotSpec` without success. Any idea ?

Thank you guys for lending me your neurons !

Comment: This would be nice to be able to do, but unfortunately not possible right now I don't think (at least using this interface).  Looking at `plotting.py`, pandas always wants to make its own subplots when doing grouped histograms.  Hence, you're only getting the very last DataFrame in your figure...

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to place the `matplotlib` `Axes` objects returned by `pd.DataFrame.hist()` into a figure with the desired layout. Unfortunately, placing new `Axes` objects into an existing `Figure` is a bit involved.

## `GridSpec` layout

Creating the layout you want is not too complicated using nested `matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec`s (see [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/gridspec_nested.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-gridspec-nested-py) for an example). Something like this.

```py
import matplotlib.gridspec as gs

num_outer_columns = 2
num_outer_rows = 2
num_inner_columns = 2
num_inner_rows = 3

outer_layout = gs.GridSpec(num_outer_rows, num_outer_columns)
inner_layout = []

for row_num in range(num_outer_rows):
    inner_layout.append([])
    for col_num in range(num_outer_columns):
        inner_layout[row_num].append(
            gs.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(
                num_inner_rows, 
                num_inner_columns, 
                outer_layout[row_num, col_num]
            )
        )
```

You can create subplots within this grid using `ax = plt.subplot(inner_layout[outer_row_num][outer_col_num][inner_row_num, inner_col_num])` and store the properly positioned `ax`s for later.

## Copying `Axes` into an existing `Figure`

Your `df.hist()` calls will produce something like this:

```py
In [1]: dframe.hist(column=x, by=y)
Out[1]:
array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x1189be160>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x118e3eb50>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x118e74d60>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x118ea8340>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x118e76d62>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x118ea9350>]],
      dtype=object)
```

Now you just have to replace the `ax` objects positioned earlier using your `inner_layout` with the `AxesSubplot` objects returned above. Unfortunately there isn't a convenient `ax.from_axes(other_ax)` method to do this, so you'll have to copy the `Axes` returned by `df.hist()` over manually by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46906599/13568555).