# Outputting two graphs at once using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

In short, I want to write a function that will output a [scatter matrix](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/visualization.html#visualization-scatter-matrix) and [boxplot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) at one time in python.
I figured I would do this by created a figure with a 2x1 plotting array. However when I run the code using a Jupyter notebook:

```
def boxplotscatter(data):
    f, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize = (12,6))
    ax[0] = scatter_matrix(data, alpha = 0.2, figsize = (6,6), diagonal = 'kde')
    ax[1] = data.boxplot()
```

I get, using data called `pdf`:

[image]

That isn't exactly what I expected -- I wanted to output the scatter matrix and below it the boxplot, not two empty grids and a boxplot embedded in a scatter matrix.

Thoughts on fixing this code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to pass the axis as an argument of your plotting function.

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize = (12,6))
def boxplotscatter(data, ax):
    ax[0] = scatter_matrix(data, alpha = 0.2, figsize = (6,6), diagonal = 'kde')
    ax[1] = data.boxplot()
```

Comment: This removes the extraneous empty grids but doesn't "pop out" the boxplot from being embedded within the scatter matrix.

Comment: Hey, I think this behaviour is due because pandas plotting is already calling a figure from within its function. That means that it will be displayed whenever is called. Anyway, given that the function returns it axes, I was checking if there was a way to decouple those axis from the figure itself and passing it to a layout that you want (so you can add different plots afterwards). However, reading this, it turns out this is not an option [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309472/matplotlib-can-i-create-axessubplot-objects-then-add-them-to-a-figure-instance).

Comment: ^ Feel free to spin this off into its own answer, I think this more or less answers it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are not actually plotting on the created axes , you are just replacing the content of your list `ax`.
I'm not very familiar with the object oriented interface for matplotlib but the right syntax would look more like `ax[i,j].plot()` rather than `ax[i] = plot()`.
Now the only real solution I can provide is using functional interface, like that :

```
def boxplotscatter(data):
    f, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize = (12,6))
    plt.subplot(211)
    scatter_matrix(data, alpha = 0.2, figsize = (6,6), diagonal = 'kde')  
    plt.subplot(212)
    data.boxplot()
```