# How to perform subplot from existing axes with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to add two (or more) axes (`ax1` and `ax2` in my example), coming from different parts of my program, to a unique raw `Figure`.

Thus, in the first part of my program, I would do:

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax1.scatter(...)
ax1.imshow()
...
```

and in a second part of this same program:

```
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax2.plot(...)
...
```

I then would like to build a figure to incorporate these two axes `ax1` and `ax2`, with something like:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_my_subplots(ax1, ax2)
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309472/matplotlib-can-i-create-axessubplot-objects-then-add-them-to-a-figure-instance)?

Comment: That's actually the way I ended up i.e. by means of a function.

Answer (score 3):

As it seems that an axis should be not linked/added to another `Figure` in Matplotlib, I came up with a more simple solution:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
do_my_stuff_with_first_axis(ax=ax1)
do_my_stuff_with_second_axis(ax=ax2)
```