# Combine two pyplot axis into single axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

Note: This is different from the following questions which make the following assumptions:

- [pyplot - copy an axes content and show it in a new figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810557/pyplot-copy-an-axes-content-and-show-it-in-a-new-figure): Deletes lines from an axis
- [Plot something in one figure, and use it again later for another figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45861656/plot-something-in-one-figure-and-use-it-again-later-for-another-figure): code to plot the lines again is available
- [matplotlib - duplicate plot from one figure to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962849/matplotlib-duplicate-plot-from-one-figure-to-another): moves onto a new empty figure

Here instead, the goal is to add lines to an existing axis which already has other lines on it.

I want to merge two axes that have been created as follows:

```
xx = np.arange(12)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(xx, np.sin(xx), label="V1")

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.plot(xx, 0*xx, label="V2")
```

Suppose I no longer have access to the code used to create these plots, but just to `fig1, ax1, fig2, ax2` objects (e.g. via pickling).

The two plots should be merged such that the output is (visually) the same (up to colors) as the output of:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xx, np.sin(xx), label="V1")
ax.plot(xx, 0*xx, label="V2")
```

I have tried

```
# move lines from ax1 to ax2
def move_lines_to_axis(ax1, ax2):
    for line in ax1.lines:
        line.remove()
        line.set_linestyle("dashed")
        line.recache(always=True)
        ax2.add_line(line)
    return ax2

ax2 = move_lines_to_axis(ax1, ax2)
ax2.figure
```

but this gives the wrong scaling.

How can I copy the lines from one figure to the other?

Fig1:
[image]
Fig2:
[image]
Expected merged figure:
[image]
What the above code gives (note the wrong y-scale of the sinus):
[image]
This seems to be related to the axis transformation, but looking at the code of `add_line`, it sets the transformation to `ax.transData`.

Comment: You need `fig1, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1)` and then plot on `ax1` and on `ax2`.  Matplotlib doesn't support moving plots created on one `figure` to another `figure`.  If you really insist, there exist clumsy workarounds.

Comment: I am precisely looking for this workaround.