# Copy all content (children?) from one subplot to another

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm coding a function to zoom in on a specific region of a simple subplot and show it as a small box over the original subplot.

I'm currently using the `inset_axes` but, to my understanding, it just creates a new subplot. The content of the original subplot have to be plotted again in the inset subplot. I'd love it to directly show everything that has been plotted in the original subplot without having to plot it again.

The code is as follows:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from typing import Iterable


ax = plt.subplot()

ax.plot((0, 1), (0, 1))
ax.fill(((0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0)))
ax.scatter((1,), (1,))


def zoom_box(
    ax: plt.Axes,
    position: Iterable[Iterable[float]] = ((.6, .6), (.9, .9)),
    xlim: Iterable[float] = (None, None),
    ylim: Iterable[float] = (None, None)
) -> plt.Axes:

    (x0, y0), (x1, y1) = position
    axins = ax.inset_axes(
        [x0, y0, x1-x0, y1-y0],
        xlim=xlim,
        ylim=ylim
    )

    # I'd like to replace the following
    axins.plot((0, 1), (0, 1))
    axins.fill(((0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0)))
    axins.scatter((1,), (1,))
    # by something like:
    # axins.copy_content(ax)

    return axins


axins = zoom_box(ax, xlim=(0.5, 1.5), ylim=(0.5, 1.5))

plt.show()
```

The code should return this figure:

[image: Don't look at this pic expecting something useful]

[Plot something in one figure, and use it again later for another figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45861656) and [copy an axes content and show it in a new figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810557) do not answer my needs because it either has to do with a new figure or just lines. Here, the code should handle Line2Ds, Polygons, and
PathCollections at least.

Comment: It is highly recommended that you put all the plotting code belonging to that subplot into a function, and then call that function twice.  Copying elements from one subplot to another is very tricky.

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for your answer. The function is located inside a package so it'd be easier to avoid writing a new function for each call.