# list reference to mpl.figure.Figure does not show plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to handle a list of figures with an object.
Unfortunately there seems to be a problem with plotting from a list of figures.

Please comment out the line in the example below and you see how the plotting breaks:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, FigureManagerQT


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.figs = [mpl.figure.Figure(),mpl.figure.Figure()]
        self.fig = mpl.figure.Figure()
        ax = self.fig.subplots()
        ax.plot([1,2],[3,4])

    def show(self):
        fig = self.fig  # works
#        fig = self.figs[0]  # does not work
        canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(fig)
        figManager = FigureManagerQT(canvas, 0)

a=Test()
a.show()
```

Result (this is what I want):
[image]

Result with line uncommented:
[image]

In some other tests I found it might be connected with destructing the object. As a list is a mutable object, this might be the connection.
I also tried (unsuccessfully) several workarounds to copy the figure object for plotting:
I used something like `fig = myCopy(self.figs[0])`
in combination with a [pickle-copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45812071/7128154).

Can you please give me some explanation of what is happening and what might be a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `__init__`, you give axes to `self.fig` and plot to this `Axes` object:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.figs = [mpl.figure.Figure(),mpl.figure.Figure()]
        self.fig = mpl.figure.Figure()
        ax = self.fig.subplots()
        ax.plot([1,2],[3,4])
```

The figure objects in `self.figs` have no `Axes` object attached to them, so they're basically empty.
As a result, what you see is an empty figure:

```
def show(self):
    fig = self.figs[0] # This is a figure with no axes
    canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(fig)
    figManager = FigureManagerQT(canvas, 0)
```

The problem with your logic is that it's not really meaningful to plot data in the `__init__` method.
Your workflow should be:

1. Initialization
2. Figure selection
3. Plot
4. Show

I suggest that you add two methods, `select_figure` and `plot`, so as to improve the overall usability of your figure manager:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = None
        self.figures = [mpl.figure.Figure(), mpl.figure.Figure()]

    def select_figure(self, index):
        self.fig = self.figures[index]

    def plot(self, x, y):
        ax = self.fig.subplots()
        ax.plot(x, y)

    def show(self):
        canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(self.fig)
        figManager = FigureManagerQT(canvas, 0)
```

Then you can implement the workflow I described above:

```
test = Test()

test.select_figure(0)
test.plot([1, 2], [3, 4])
test.show()

test.select_figure(1)
test.plot([3, 4], [5, 6])
test.show()
```

Comment: oh man, this is so embarrassing that I forgot to add an Axes object to my figures in my list!!! What I presented was only a minimal example (which now does not reproduce my error anymore). I will continue checking these days and come back with adjustments.

Comment: @MarkusDutschke Haha no worries :) Don't hesitate to open a new question if you come across another issue in your code!

Comment: ok, things got even more embarrassing, as I found the issue of my original code: I had a destructor defined and forgotten long time ago, which was responsible for the unexpected behavior. Thank you for your answer. That made me look for the simple solutions. I think the take home message here is: LOOK FOR THE VERY SIMPLE THINGS BEFORE HITTING ON THE COMPLEX.