# How to make 2 existing bar plots into one subplot

Tags: python, excel, subplot

I have made 2 bar plots, using  ax1 and ax2. I am using matplotlib and pandas. I have imported the data from an Excel file.

My code currently looks something like this:

```
ax1 = df.plot.bar(x='Column name in excel', y='Column name in excel', Other specifications, such as color and width.
ax2 = Same as ax1, but different columns used from excel file.
```

Then the next bit of my code is:

```
ax1.set_ylabel
ax1.set_xlabel
ax1.set_title
```

and so on. The same with ax2.

I have got 2 perfect plots and I am very happy with them. I just would like to have them next to each other horizontally as subplots, so I can export them as one image file and have a supertitle (suptitle) above both.

How can I do this? I have quite a lot of code and it would be a shame to have to start from scratch. Maybe there is a piece of code that does this and I could just add in below?

Comment: Adding a pandas tag in the question might help you to get better reach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyplot - copy an axes content and show it in a new figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810557/pyplot-copy-an-axes-content-and-show-it-in-a-new-figure)