# Copy an axes content and show it in an existing figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, mne-python

The problem is there are 2 seperate `Figure` objects displayed on the screen. Each `Figure` object contains an `Axes` object. How can I overwrite / replace the `Axes` object in Figure 1, with the `Axes` object from Figure 2?

In other words:

1. We have some data called A.
2. We plot the data called A.
3. The plot is returned in a new Figure and displayed.
4. We have some data called B.
5. We plot the data called B.
6. Now we want to copy and overwrite the `Axes` containing data B into the `Axes` containing data A

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.ion()

# Draw the first figure and plot
x_1 = np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 100)
y_1 = np.sin(x_1)

figure_1 = plt.figure()
axes_1 = figure_1.add_subplot(111)
line_1, = axes_1.plot(x_1, y_1, 'b-')
figure_1.canvas.draw()

# Draw the second figure and plot
x_2 = np.linspace(0, 9*np.pi, 100)
y_2 = np.sin(x_2)

figure_2 = plt.figure()
axes_2 = figure_2.add_subplot(111)
line_2 = axes_2.plot(x_2, y_2, 'r-')
figure_2.canvas.draw()

# Now clear figure_1's axes and replace it with figure_2's axis
figure_1.get_axes()[0].clear()
figure_1.add_axes(axes_2)
figure_1.canvas.draw()
print("Done")
```

Using the `add_axes()` method is raising `ValueError "The Axes must have been created in the present figure"`.

Is there a way to detatch the Axes from the current figure so that it can be added to the other one?

There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810557/pyplot-copy-an-axes-content-and-show-it-in-a-new-figure) question which addresses copying an Axes and displaying in a new figure, however I want to display it in an existing figure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyplot - copy an axes content and show it in a new figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810557/pyplot-copy-an-axes-content-and-show-it-in-a-new-figure)

Comment: Thanks yes I have seen that. It is not far off what I need to do, however maybe a better title for this question would be "copy an axes content and show it in an existing figure"

Comment: No difference. You cannot copy axes objects.

Comment: Yes it does explain that you cannot copy axes objects. However that post was eventually successful as they were able to copy a figure using pickle, and then display the axes in a new seperate figure. Unfortunatly it does not explain how to copy the axes and display in an exisiting figure.

Answer (score -1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# b: blue, g: green, r: red, c: cyan, m: magenta, y: yellow, k: black, w: white

##################################################################################
# EQUATIONS
##################################################################################

x_1 = np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 100)
y_1 = np.sin(x_1)

#If you change the equation with a conditional/loop, you will change the plot

##################################################################################
# LABELING
##################################################################################

plt.xlabel('x axis')
plt.ylabel('y axis')
plt.title('Data_VIsualization')

##################################################################################
# PLOTTING
##################################################################################

plt.plot(x_1, y_1, color='b', linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, however I do not need to change the equation. My problem is about copying an ```Axes``` object from one ```Figure``` object and inserting into a seperate ```Figure``` object