# Copy an axis into a gridspec

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-gridspec

I have a function that returns a `fig, ax` pair. However I want to put that result inside a subplot of my `gridspec`.

```
fig, ax = draw_football_field(dimensions, size) # this is the output that I want to copy to another subplot

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(18, 9)
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[3:6, 1:3], zorder=1) #this is the target subplot
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's non-trivial to pass an `Axes` object created on one `Figure` to a different instance of a `Figure` object as `Axes` are designed to live on one specific `Figure` instance. [See this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45812071/2694260).

I would recommend changing your `draw_footlball_field` function to accept an `Axes` object.

```
def draw_football_field(axes, other_args):
    axes.plot(other_args)
    return axes
```

Now you can do something along the lines of:

```
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(18, 9)
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[3:6, 1:3], zorder=1) #this is the target subplot
ax = draw_football_field(ax, other_args) # modify axes instance from 'this' fig
```