# Combine multiple matplotlib axes without re-plotting data

Tags: python, matplotlib

*optional context feel free to skip: I'm currently using cartopy and matplotlib to read in and plot weather model data on a map. I have three different fields I'm plotting: temperature, wind, and surface pressure. I'm using contourf, barbs, and contour respectively to plot each field. I want one image for each field, and then I'd like one image that contains all three fields overlaid on a single map. Currently I'm doing this by plotting each field individually, saving each of the individual images, then replotting all three fields on a single ax and a new fig, and saving that fig. Since the data takes a while to plot, I would like to be able to plot each of the single fields, then combine the axes into one final image.*

I'd like to be able to combine multiple matplotlib axes without replotting the data on the axes. I'm not sure if this is possible, but doing so would be a pretty major time and performance saver. An example of what I'm talking about:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x1 = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
x2 = x1 + 5
y = np.sin(x1)

firstFig = plt.figure()
firstAx = firstFig.gca()
firstAx.scatter(x1, y, 1, "red")
firstAx.set_xlim([0, 12])
secondFig = plt.figure()
secondAx = secondFig.gca()
secondAx.scatter(x2, y, 1, "blue")
secondAx.set_xlim([0, 12])

firstFig.savefig("1.png")
secondFig.savefig("2.png")
```

This generates two images, 1.png and 2.png.

[image: 1.png]

[image: 2.png]

Is it possible to save a third file, 3.png that would look something like the following, but without calling `scatter` again, because for my dataset, the actual plotting takes a long time?

[image: 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to save images of your plots and you don't intend to further use the `Figure` objects, you can use the following after saving "2.png".

```
# get the scatter object from the first figure
scatter = firstAx.get_children()[0]
# remove it from this collection so you can assign it to a new axis
# the axis reassignment will raise an error if it already belongs to another axis
scatter.remove()
scatter.axes = secondAx
# now you can add it to your new axis
secondAx.add_artist(scatter)
secondFig.savefig("3.png")
```

This modifies both figures, as it removes a scatter from one and adds it to another. If for some reason you want to preserve them, you can [copy the contents of `secondFig` to a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810557/pyplot-copy-an-axes-content-and-show-it-in-a-new-figure/45812071) and then add the scatter to that. However, this will still modify the first plot as you have to remove the scatter from there.

Comment: so thanks for the response, this basically confirms for me that something like this is possible, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work perfectly. Specifically the scaling doesn't work properly. 

https://i.imgur.com/FIXCGqO.jpg 


Over the past few days I've tried learning about transformations on my own (and I haven't given up yet...), but I wanted to know if you knew how to fix this.
[code](https://paste.bingner.com/paste/d54jf)

Comment: @SamGardner I have no idea how you generated that result. Your initial dataset + the code in my answer can produce your desired result. If this red line is a different sine wave, e.g., scaled or shifted, it's possible it's outside the [-1, 1] range in the y axis. In that case you'd need to set new limits for the axes to see the whole curve. You can try `y0, y1 = firstAx.get_ylim(); y2, y3 = secondAx.get_ylim(); secondAx.set_ylim(min(y0, y2), max(y1, y3))`.  And same for the x-axis limits.

Comment: hmm, so this is really strange, running the exact same code on linux generates the plot I want, but running it on my mac does the weird shifting thing. 

I'll do more testing and try to figure out why, but thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @SamGardner Long shot, but I believe mac uses a different backend by default and it may be the culprit. Check it with `matplotlib.get_backend()` and change it with `matplotlib.use(<another backend>)`. See the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.use) for a list of backends. Try TkAgg if possible.