# Draw an Arc as Polygon using Start, End, Center and Radius using Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have used the below code with only inputs `start_point` and `end_point`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches

start_point = (25, 50)
end_point = (50, 25)
center = (25, 25)
radius = (25
# We need to some how automatically calculate this midpoint
mid_point = (45, 45)
verts = [start_point, mid_point, end_point]
codes = [Path.MOVETO, Path.CURVE3, Path.CURVE3]#, Path.CLOSEPOLY]

path = Path(verts, codes)
shape = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='none', lw=0.75)
plt.gca().add_patch(shape)
plt.axis('scaled')
```

I get the following output

[image]

I need the following output (I created the below output using `MS Paint`)

[*Explanation*: Converted the arc into set of points joined as straight lines. I need those set of points as list]

[image]

Comment: I do not understand the question. If you already have created the desired output, what do you need help with?

Comment: I created the desired output using MS Paint (I have edited the question with that information). I need the output using `matplotlib` in `python`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the coordinates along a Path that has been defined via curves (`CURVE3` or `CURVE4`) you may use the `Path`'s `.to_polygons()` method. This will give a `N x 2` shaped array of coordinates.

```
poly, = path.to_polygons()
plt.plot(*zip(*poly), marker="o", ls="None")
```

[image]

---

There is no way to manipulate the number of points created by `.to_polygon`. If that is a requirement, you may instead create your [own Bezier curve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46916371/4124317) from the given points as shown below. Here we choose 32 points along the path.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import binom

bernstein = lambda n, k, t: binom(n,k)* t**k * (1.-t)**(n-k)

def bezier(points, num=200):
    N = len(points)
    t = np.linspace(0, 1, num=num)
    curve = np.zeros((num, 2))
    for i in range(N):
        curve += np.outer(bernstein(N - 1, i, t), points[i])
    return curve

start_point = (25, 50)
end_point = (50, 25)
mid_point = (45, 45)

nodes1 = np.array([start_point, mid_point, end_point])
curve1 = bezier(nodes1, num=32)

plt.plot(curve1[:,0], curve1[:,1], color="red", ls="", marker="o", ms=3)
plt.axis('scaled')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Can we decide on the number of coordinates to be formed on the arc? Is there some parameter for that?

Comment: Unfortunately that does not seem to be possible. But instead you may of course create your own polygon using a Bezier curve. I updated the answer.

Comment: Wonderful. This is exactly what I need. Cheers @ImportanceOfBeingErnest