# Moving Collections between axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

While playing with [ImportanceOfBeingErnest's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48915069/190597) to move artists between axes, I thought it would easy to extend it to collections (such as `PathCollections` generated by `plt.scatter`) as well. No such luck:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pickle

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
y = np.exp(-x**2/2)/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)
a = np.random.normal(size=10000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)

pickle.dump(fig, open("/tmp/figA.pickle", "wb"))
# plt.show()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(a, bins=20, density=True, ec="k")

pickle.dump(fig, open("/tmp/figB.pickle", "wb"))
# plt.show()

plt.close("all")

# Now unpickle the figures and create a new figure
#    then add artists to this new figure

figA = pickle.load(open("/tmp/figA.pickle", "rb"))
figB = pickle.load(open("/tmp/figB.pickle", "rb"))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for figO in [figA, figB]:
    lists = [figO.axes[0].lines, figO.axes[0].patches, figO.axes[0].collections]
    addfunc = [ax.add_line, ax.add_patch, ax.add_collection]
    for lis, func in zip(lists, addfunc):
        for artist in lis[:]:
            artist.remove()
            artist.axes = ax
            # artist.set_transform(ax.transData) 
            artist.figure = fig
            func(artist)

ax.relim()
ax.autoscale_view()

plt.close(figA)
plt.close(figB)
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Removing `artist.set_transform(ax.transData)` (at least when calling `ax.add_collection`) seems to help a little, but notice that the y-offset is still off:
[image]
How does one properly move collections from one axes to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scatter has an IdentityTransform as master transform. The data transform is the internal offset transform. One would hence need to treat the scatter separately.

```
from matplotlib.collections import PathCollection
from matplotlib.transforms import IdentityTransform

# ...

if type(artist) == PathCollection:
    artist.set_transform(IdentityTransform())
    artist._transOffset = ax.transData
else:
    artist.set_transform(ax.transData)
```

Unfortunately, there is no `set_offset_transform` method, such that one needs to replace the [`._transOffset`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/9b48fd82a6e66df6fce9c99e56e9e75def5afe9a/lib/matplotlib/collections.py#L167) attribute to set the offset transform.

[image]