# Copy axis instance from one subplots figure to another

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to assign the subplot axes data that I set for one figure to another as below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,2,sharey=True)
ax1[0].plot(x,y)
ax1[0].set_xlabel("x")
ax1[0].set_ylabel("y")

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(4,4,sharex=True,sharey=True)

ax2[0,0] = ax1[0] # I was expecting this to set all the axis labels and plot data from ax1 



plt.show()
```

Note that I have seen the answer in [matplotlib: can I create AxesSubplot objects, then add them to a Figure instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309472/matplotlib-can-i-create-axessubplot-objects-then-add-them-to-a-figure-instance)

And I tried using the `fig2.axes.append(ax1)` but this doesnt work. I would like all the properties that were set on `ax1[0]` of `fig1` to be copied over and displayed in `fig2`

Comment: If you have seen those answers, why does your code not reflect this? Also make sure you have read *all* answers. If you have problems using another solution, share the code you have a problem with and clearly state what's wrong with it. Once the question is edited with a [mcve] of the attempt, don't forget to notify me, otherwise noone will notice the changes.