# How to add seaborn axes to matplotlib figure with subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a function to return a seaborn plot. I want to add multiple seaborn plots to a figure by looping. I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309472/matplotlib-can-i-create-axessubplot-objects-then-add-them-to-a-figure-instance) for matplotlib but not sure how to apply it to seaborn.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plotf(df_x):
    g = sns.lineplot(data=df_x[['2016','2017','2018']])
    g.set_xticks(range(0,12))
    g.set_xticklabels(['Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan'])
    return g

df = pd.DataFrame({'Period': list(range(1,13)),
                           '2016': np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=12),
                           '2017': np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=12),
                           '2018': np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=12)}) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3)
```

I would like to see 3 plots in `ax[0], ax[1], ax[2]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply assign the axis on which you want to plot as input to the function and explicitly specify on which axis you want to plot in sns.lineplot

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plotf(df_x,ax):
    g = sns.lineplot(data=df_x[['2016','2017','2018']],ax=ax)
    g.set_xticks(range(0,12))
    g.set_xticklabels(['Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan'])
    return g

df = pd.DataFrame({'Period': list(range(1,13)),
                           '2016': np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=12),
                           '2017': np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=12),
                           '2018': np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=12)}) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3)
plotf(df,ax[0])
plotf(df,ax[1])
plotf(df,ax[2])
```

[image: output]