# How to subplot a matplotlib table by using a custom plot function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create a function that takes axes of a subplot as a parameter and return a matplotlib table.

I was able to do this for barplots and lineplots  using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55593583/how-to-add-seaborn-axes-to-matplotlib-figure-with-subplots). But trying the same for a table gives me an "`error table() got multiple values for argument 'ax'`"

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'var':['a','b','c','d'],'col1':[1,2,3,4],'col2':[1,4,9,16]})
df.set_index('var', inplace=True)


def plot_reg(df_x, ax=None):
    g = plt.table(cellText=df_x.values,
                  rowLabels=df_x.index,
                  colLabels=df_x.columns,loc='center', ax=ax)
    return g

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5), ncols=2)
plot_reg(df, ax=ax[1])
```

I would like to get a similar result like the figure below.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5), ncols=2)
ax[1].table(cellText=df.values,rowLabels=df.index,colLabels=df.columns,loc='right')
# ax[1].axis('tight')
ax[1].axis('off')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question, but you could write your function as:

```
def plot_reg(df_x, ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()  # either use the value passed as argument, or the current Axes
    g = ax.table(cellText=df_x.values,
                  rowLabels=df_x.index,
                  colLabels=df_x.columns,loc='center')
    return g
```