# Join separate boxplot figure files

Tags: python, matplotlib, pickle

I have three boxplot figures that I am loading using `pickle` and I would like to join and plot them side-by-side. It seems that the recommendation is to plot one figure to begin with and use `matplotlib subplots`. However, due to the nature of the data this would be difficult and it is easiest to make three separate figure files first. All three figures have the same y axis limits and the same x ticks.

How can I join them such that they are side-by-side on the same row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create a new figure with the layout you want, then insert the `Axes` from the existing figures into it. You can get the `Axes` from an existing figure with only one set of `Axes` using `fig.axes[0]`, then insert it into a new figure by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46906599/13568555).

---

PS Emersons unite!